# Vertically align last element in a div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to make just the class `type` to be vertically aligned to the bottom, but I've been failing in my attempts. Perhaps anyone could recommend me a better method?
I can't make the box smaller because the rest of the divs will be all equal heights.

**html:**

```
<div class="medium_container">
    <div class="medium_item">
        <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100"></a>
        <div class="medium">111111111</div>
        <div class="brand">22222222</div>
        <div class="titles">333333333</div>
        <div class="country">44444444<br />444444444</div>
        <span class="type">55555555555</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.medium_container {display:block;}
.medium_item {
display: inline-block;
padding:7px;
margin:10px 3px;
width:170px;
border:1px solid black;
height:400px;
}
.medium_item img {
width:170px;
height:100px;
}
.type {
vertical-align: bottom;
display: table-cell;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QPC4P/1/%20jsfiddle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can absolutely position `.type` relative to it's parent `.medium_item` as follows

```
.medium_item {
  position:relative; /*add this*/
  display: inline-block;
  padding:7px;
  margin:10px 3px;
  width:170px;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:400px;
}
.type {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position:absolute; /*add this*/
  bottom:0; /*add this*/
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QPC4P/2/)